# Pattern Matching - Regex

Tags: java, regex

**User input Format:**

> [fieldname1] comparator [fieldvalue1,fieldvalue2,value3],[fieldname2]
>   comparator [fieldvalue1,value2,..],..

**Need to parse this into:**

> 1.[fieldname1] comparator [fieldvalue1,fieldvalue2,value3]
>
> 2.[fieldname2] comparator [fieldvalue1,value2,..] and so on

(ie)each field along with its comparator and value has to be separated.
whereas comparator will be any one of the below:

> <=|>=|=|is|<|>|startswith|Starts with|Beginswith|Begins with|Ends
>   with|Endswith|

contains

**Regex used by me :**

> ([(.)+?](\s)*(<=|>=|=|is|<|>|startswith|Starts
>   with|Beginswith|Begins with|Ends
>   with|Endswith|contains)(\s)*[(.)+?](\,)*)

**Example:**
[company] contains [abc,efg],[email] contains [cdf,test]
above is parsed properly no issues.

**Problem:**
When field name or field value contains symbol "[" or "]" the parsing goes wrong .

**example :**
[company] contains [ab[]c,efg],[email] contains [siva,test]

Above is valid but since [] is used as delimiter it stops parsing till [company] contains [ab[] but i want it to parse properly as above eg,

1.[company] contains [ab[]c,efg]

2.[email] contains [siva,test]

**Thanks.**

Comment: What language/tool are you using?  I'm not sure you can get the numbering you want using pure regex.

Comment: Language is JAVA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with this regex:

```
,(?=(?:(?:[^\\[\\]]*[\\]\\[]){2})*[^\\[\\]]*$)
```

Splitting your target string should give you list of splitted result set. Over which you can apply your comparator matching easily

```
final String regex = ",(?=(?:(?:[^\\[\\]]*[\\]\\[]){2})*[^\\[\\]]*$)";
final String string = "[company] contains [ab[]c,efg],[email] contains [siva,test]";
String[] res=string.split(regex);
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(res).toString());
```

By using this you get the exptected result. All you may need to check is, if each index contains the correct comparator as you have shown. if not, then remove that from the array.

The above code outputs:

```
[
  [company] contains [ab[]c,efg],
  [email] contains [siva,test]
]
```

[Regex101Demo](https://regex101.com/r/KTzHEO/1/)

> Explanation:

Whenever a , is found -->

```
,(?=(?:(?:[^\\[\\]]*[\\]\\[]){2})*[^\\[\\]]*$)
```

a positive look ahead runs until the end of string  where the following line

`(?:[^\\[\\]]*[\\]\\[]){2})*` ensures that - if a bracket is found it is found twice. Then the last * indicates 0 or more repetition of of bracket pair.

Why is that important ? From any comma , and afterwards you count number of [ and ] brackets. And you will see that you only need to split by that comma if only even number of brackets are there afterwards. and you dont want to split for commas for whom odd number of bracket comes afterwards. That is the explanation.

For entire breakdown of the regex you can look into the link where full explanation is given character by character in the right top section.

Comment: Thank you!
can u please explain the regex u have mentioned.
**existing code**:
`Pattern p = Pattern.compile(criteriaRegex,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    int crtCount=0;
    Matcher m = p.matcher(criteria);
    String[] criteriaArr = new String[100];
    int start=0,end=0;    
    while (m.find()) {  
     start = m.start(0);
     end = m.end(0);
     String temp = criteria.substring(start,end);
     criteriaArr[crtCount] = temp;
     crtCount++;`
**thanks**

Comment: @Siva I have added some explanation.

Comment: Thank you so much . It worked fine ! and I applied     `String nameValRegex = "(?i)(<=|>=|=|is|<|>|startswith|Starts with|Beginswith|Begins with|Ends with|Endswith|contains)(?=(?:(?:[^\\[\\]]*[\\]\\[]){2})*[^\\[\\]]*$)";`
this regex for separating comparator, field name and value .If there is better way please suggest.
*thanks Rizwan*!

Comment: Would appreciate if you can accept it as answer then. process: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

So basically you need to split the string at each `,` that is between `]` and `[`.

If you use google's guava, you can use the `Splitter` and split on a regex with positve lookbefore `]` and positive lookbehind `[`

```
String s = "[fieldname1] comparator [fieldvalue1,fieldvalue2,value3],[fieldname2] comparator [fieldvalue1,value2]";
Pattern stringPattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\]),(?=\\[)");
Iterable<String> split = Splitter.on(stringPattern).omitEmptyStrings().split(s);
split.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, we must define a regexp that matches the name, another one that matches the comparator, and a third one that matches a value:

```
private static final String NAME_RE = "[A-Za-z0-9_]+";
private static final String VALUE_RE = "[A-Za-z0-9_\\[\\]\\.]+";
private static final String COMPARATOR_RE
        = "<=|>=|=|is|<|>|startswith|Starts with|Beginswith|Begins with|Ends with|Endswith|Contains";
```

We can now create the pattern that combines these sub-regexps:

```
private static final String RE = "\\s*\\[(" + NAME_RE + ")\\]\\s*"
        + "(" + COMPARATOR_RE + ")\\s*\\[\\s*("
        + VALUE_RE + "(?:\\s*,\\s*" + VALUE_RE + ")*)\\s*\\]"
        + "(?:\\s*,\\s*(.*))?";
private static final Pattern PATTERN
        = Pattern.compile(RE, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

Note that it matches a single rule that may or may not be followed by a comma and the other rules.

The parsing of a source string must iterate the rules:

```
private static void parse(String source) {
    String s = source;
    while (s != null) {
        Matcher matcher = PATTERN.matcher(s);
        if (!matcher.matches()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid syntax: " + source);
        }
        String name = matcher.group(1);
        String comparator = matcher.group(2);
        String values = matcher.group(3);
        s = matcher.group(4);
        System.out.println("[" + name + "] " + comparator + " [" + values + "]");
    }
}
```

Now let's try to parse your two examples:

```
private static final String EXAMPLE1 = "[company] contains [abc,efg],[email] contains [cdf,test]";
private static final String EXAMPLE2 = "[company] contains [ab[]c,efg],[email] contains [siva,test]";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    parse(EXAMPLE1);
    parse(EXAMPLE2);
}
```

It produces the following output:

```
[company] contains [abc,efg]
[email] contains [cdf,test]
[company] contains [ab[]c,efg]
[email] contains [siva,test]
```

UPDATE:

Note that the contents of a value must be restricted because if "efg]" and "[email] contains [cdf" are both acceptable value, then there is no way to know if these examples are composed of one or two rules.

UPDATE 2:

Here is a pretty loose regexp for VALUE_RE:

```
private static final String VALUE_RE
        = "[^,\\[\\]]*(?:\\[[^,\\[\\]]*\\][^,\\[\\]]*)*";
```

Here a value cannot contain any comma, and only balanced brackets, without nesting.

Comment: But when i tried to add other characters to the field name it was causing some error `private static final String NAME_RE = "[A-Za-z0-9_,\\[\\]\\s~`!@#$%^&*\\(\\)-\\+'\"\\.,\\/\\\\\\?=]+";
`
`private static final String EXAMPLE2 = "[LastName] = [test],[FullName] = [te],[Exchange Rate] is [1],[Decimal 1] = [12],[Companynumber] <= [123457]";
`**Thanks Maurice**